# Looping checkboxes and checked if exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to generate a list of checkboxes, and make them checked if they exists for a product.  Kinda like Products <-> ProductsCategories <-> Categories

Kinda like:

```
<%
    foreach(var x in Model.Categories)
{
    %>
    <%= Html.CheckBox("CategoryID", checked if exists in Model.Product.Categories)%>
    <%
}
%>
```

How is that done?

/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("CategoryID", Model.Product.Categories.Contains(x))%>
```

Hope that helps,

Kindness,

Dan